# Scipy.stats.anderson returns an array instead of a float as described in documentation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am attempting to use the Anderson-Darling method to test if my residuals follow a normal distribution using Scipy.stats.anderson,  I'm using Scipy v1.0.0, Python3.5 in a Linux environment.

However, instead of returning a float for the test statistic as described in the documentation, what is returned is an array.

My input is a 1-dimensional numpy array.  Below is the output.

Thanks for your help!

[AndesonResults from Scipy.stats.anderson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELLEK.jpg)

Comment: paste your code as text so we can try to recreate the problem see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I found the problem.   I was using a dataframe to hold the initial data and then creating a numpy 1d array which I was using as input to the anderson function.  When I used a list as input instead of an array, the function returns a float for the test statistic as described in the documentation.  The documentation says the input should be an array of sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
results = anderson(rez.flatten(), dist='norm')
```

I think the problem is that your `rez` is has a shape of `(n,1)` rather than `(n,)`, which is expected for 1d arrays by the `anderson` code.

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the problem!  I also found that using a list works as well.